# How to use JavaMail to read emails with multiple labels from Google Mail (Gmail)?

Tags: java, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

In Google Mail, I would like to get messages that has been assigned multiple labels. For example, if in the Inbox we have three emails:

Email_1 with Label_A and Label_B

Email_2 with Label_A and Label_B

Email_3 with Label_A and Label_C

then I want to select those with Label_A and Label_B at the same time, which are Email_1 and Email_2. Currently the following codes work for one-label situation, but is there any way to do it with more than one label? Thanks.

---

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", -1, "abc@def.com", "password");

Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder();

folder = folder.getFolder("Label_A");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);      

int totalMessages = folder.getMessageCount();
int newMessages = folder.getNewMessageCount();
System.out.println("Total messages = " + totalMessages);
System.out.println("New messages = " + newMessages);
```

---

Comment: I have a very similar problem.  I'd like to be able to say that a message has two labels.  I can easily get messages from both folders, but I'm not sure the right way to correlate the two messages.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
private Store store;
private Folder Label_A; 
private Folder Label_B; 
    ...
        Label_A = store.getFolder("Label_A"); 
        Label_B = store.getFolder("Label_B");
```

Comment: How do you correlate that a message is in each of them?  The sequence is different, the UID is different and the MessageID cannot be trusted to be there or be unique?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to write my own raw IMAP commands to allow javamail to use Gmail's IMAP extensions.  Then this works.

[Access to Gmail labels: X-GM-LABELS](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/imap/#x-gm-labels)

You then issue: folder.doCommand() with your command.